# UnityWebRequest - error: 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, http, unity-game-engine, get, request

I'm preparing my game for publishing on ArmorGames.com
        I use their [API](https://armorgames.readme.io/docs/2_authentication_service#section-parameters) to get the id of the current user:

https://services.armorgames.com/services/rest/v1/authenticate/user.json

When I click on this link in the browser, I get the correct answer.
            When sending a GET request through my build, I get an error:

HTTP / 1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

```
IEnumerator GetText(Action<string> callback) 
    {

        string url;
        url = "https://services.armorgames.com/services/rest/v1/authenticate/user.​json";
        UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);
        www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        www.SetRequestHeader("accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9" ); 
        www.SetRequestHeader("accept-encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
        www.SetRequestHeader("accept-language", "ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7");


        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if(www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError) {
            Debug.Log("MyError: " + www.error);
            callback(null);
        }
        else {

                Debug.Log("resp:" + www.downloadHandler.text);             
                callback(www.downloadHandler.text);                      
        }
    }
```

I try to send request with headers and without. Nothing helps.
        What can be the problem?

Comment: Shouldnt it be returning json not xml, or html or xhtml.... I think you blocked the wrong types there. as you said to only accept them, surely you wanted application/json ?

Comment: @BugFinder I try to reproduce headers from browser request (https://img-host.ru/5Nie.png). I also try not to add any headers in unity, but I've got the same result.

Comment: @BugFinder \*/\* in accept header should be suitable for everything, but it doesn't help. A also try to add application/json to accept, same bad result.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit of googling was in order.

https://forum.unity.com/threads/unitywebrequest-error-415-unsupported-media-type.801297/

Which isnt obvious from your pasted code although the lack of colouring in visual studio gave it away

there is a space after user. and json..

remove the space

Comment: Thank you. This is also my post on unity.com. But I thought that forum layout past this space. After your words I find invisible space symbol in VS code. Thank you, now all is okey!

Comment: I did not think that there are invisible spaces in the VScode. And the comment concerned the code in the text of the letter